# ¿Como utilizar un eje secundario en ggplot2 para dos variables distintas?

Tags: r, ggplot

Necesito hacer un gráfico combinado de barras y líneas, en el cual cada uno tenga su eje. En este caso en las barras se encuentran los casos confirmados de una enfermedad y en las líneas las coberturas de vacunación de esa enfermedad. Según el año en el eje x.

Logré realizar el gráfico pero ambos utilizan el eje izquierdo, no sé cómo hacer para que las líneas utilicen el eje derecho.

El código es así:

```
ggplot(data = coberturas, mapping = aes(x = coberturas$ANIO, y = coberturas$Casos)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + labs(x="Año", y="Casos confirmados") + geom_line(aes(x=ANIO, y= coberturas$vacuna1, fill = coberturas$vacuna1) + geom_line(aes(x=ANIO, y=coberturas$vacuna2) + geom_line(aes(x=ANIO, y=coberturas$vacuna3) + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.* 1, name = "Cobertura"))
```

El dataframe de datos es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El gráfico es así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando utilizas la función `sec_axis` multiplicas el eje por 1, con lo que como resultado te aparece el mismo eje que a la izquierda, este multiplicador deberá ser diferente.

Comment: El tema es que independientemente de los valores del eje de la derecha, el gráfico de líneas está utilizando el eje de la izquierda

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola @Julieta!

Para empezar, comentar que en el código que has subido faltan en cada `geom_line` un paréntesis por cerrar. Entiendo que para obtener el gráfico esto lo tienes solucionado, pero por si acaso lo comento.

Respecto a la duda que comentas, basándome en el siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales) entiendo que la mejor forma de conseguir el gráfico como deseas es realizar una transformación de los datos. Siguiendo tu ejemplo, a continuación escribo qué es lo que hay que hacer de forma detallada:

```
# Determinar los límites de los dos ejes Y que se desean representar
  # EJE PRIMARIO
    ylim.prim <- c(0, 160)
  # EJE SECUNDARIO
    ylim.sec <- c(0, 450)
```

Los datos que deseas representar en el eje secundario necesitan de una transformación lineal (y = a + b*x) donde `a`y `b` se calculan a partir de los límites anteriores de la siguiente forma:

```
    b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
    a <- ylim.prim[1] - b*ylim.sec[1]
```

Finalmente, se realiza la representación teniendo en cuenta los cambios que se han de introducir en `geom_line()` y en `scale_y_continuous()`:

```
ggplot(coberturas, aes(ANIO, Casos)) +
    geom_bar(stat="Identity", fill = "cyan1", col = "black") +
    labs(x="Año", y="Casos confirmados") +
    geom_line(aes(y = a + vacuna1*b), color = "red") +
    geom_line(aes(y = a + vacuna2*b), color = "blue") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = a + vacuna3*b), color = "darkgreen") + 
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.-a)/b, name = "Cobertura"))
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo, los gráficos de doble escala son una mala idea por que confunden más de lo que explican, para más detalle te sugiero leer [Dual-Scaled Axes in Graphs Are They Ever the Best Solution?](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf)

Ahora bien, si aún quieres implementar uno, en tu caso, es bastante sencillo por que aunque estemos hablando de "peras y bananas", las escalas tienen valores en un rango bastante parecido, por lo que lo único que habría que resolver es ajustar las etiquetas de la escala secundaria.

Primero que nada voy a manipular los datos a una forma que sea más cómoda de trabajar en `ggplot` esto es llevarlo a un formato "largo":

```
library(tidyverse)

coberturas <- read.table(text = "ANIO vacuna1 vacuna2 vacuna3 Casos
2022 83.8 74.2 68.3 155
2021 81.2 75.7 67.4 123
2020 75.0 75.0 61.1 99
2019 82.9 72.6 63.5 15", header=TRUE)
coberturas$ANIO <- as.factor(coberturas$ANIO)

coberturas %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ANIO) -> coberturas_longer
```

Y ahora armamos dos `data.frames` para cada indicador:

```
coberturas_longer %>% 
  filter(name == "Casos") %>% 
  select(ANIO, value) -> casos

coberturas_longer %>% 
  filter(str_like(name, "%vacuna%")) %>% 
  select(ANIO, name, value) -> vacunas
```

Para el factor de ajuste:

```
ajuste <-  max(vacunas$value) / max(casos$value)
```

Y finalmente el gráfico:

```
ggplot(data = casos, 
       mapping = aes(x = ANIO, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "cyan1") + 
  labs(x="Año", color="") +
  geom_line(data = vacunas, 
            aes(x=ANIO, y=value * ajuste, colour = name, group=name),
            linewidth = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Casos confirmados", 
                     sec.axis=sec_axis(~./(ajuste), name="Cobertura")) +
  
  theme_light()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comentarios

- Esto `aes(x = coberturas$ANIO, y = coberturas$Casos))` no es lo que se debería hacer, de hecho las últimas versiones de `ggplot` lanzan una advertencia, lo correcto sería hacer:  `aes(x = ANIO, y = Casos))`
- La idea de "pivotear" los datos es para evitar tener que definir 3 `geom_line()` y simplemente usar uno y la dimensión del nombre de la vacuna como el `fill`